# Any way to login to Instagram using sessionid and csrftoken cookies?

Tags: http, cookies, instagram

I am trying to create a JavaScript bot that can access and download all direct messages on Instagram by utilizing the session token and CSRF token. Initially, I attempted to manually generate an HTTP request using the tokens, but was unsuccessful in logging in. I am inquiring if there exists a method to log in through the use of cookies. Such a capability would prove beneficial for the bot's functionality.